# Volume (Balance) Control for XP/Vista

Tags: c++, windows, windows-vista, audio

Is there a method for controlling the Balance of the Wave output that will work on both XP and Vista?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vista has a new api for everything related to mixers and audio, per process legacy api's should still work, but to change global volume, you would have to look at the new COM interfaces added to Vista

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/CoreAudio.aspx) should get you started

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at this?

> waveOutSetVolume
>
> The waveOutSetVolume function sets the
>   volume level of the specified
>   waveform-audio  output device.

It uses Winmm.lib.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713762.aspx